# wanting a good memory + disk caching solution

Tags: caching, memcached, distributed-caching, memcachedb

I'm currently storing generated HTML pages in a memcached in-memory cache. This works great, however I am wanting to increase the storage capacity of the cache beyond available memory. What I would really like is:

1. memcached semantics (i.e. not reliable, just a cache)
2. memcached api preferred (but not required)
3. large in-memory first level cache (MRU)
4. huge on-disk second level cache (main)
5. evicted from on-disk cache at maximum storage using LRU or LFU
6. proven implementation

In searching for a solution I've found the following solutions but they all miss my marks in some way. Does anyone know of either:

- other options that I haven't considered
- a way to make memcachedb do evictions

Already considered are:

[memcachedb](http://memcachedb.org/)

- best fit but doesn't do evictions: explicitly "not a cache"
- can't see any way to do evictions (either manual or automatic)

[tugela cache](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Tugela_Cache)

- abandoned, no support
- don't want to recommend it to customers

[nmdb](http://blitiri.com.ar/p/nmdb/)

- doesn't use memcache api
- new and unproven
- don't want to recommend it to customers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that later versions of memcachedb can be cleaned up manually if desired using the [rget](http://memcachedb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/rget.txt) command and storing the expiry time in the data record. Of course, this means that I pound both the server and network with requests for the entire data block even though I only want the expiry time. Not the best solution but seemingly the only one currently available.

Answer (score 0):

[Tokyo Cabinet](http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/)/[Tokyo Tyrant](http://1978th.net/tokyotyrant/)?

Comment: Ta for the suggestion, but it isn't a cache solution.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with [EhCache](http://ehcache.org) and it works very good. It has in memory cache and disk storage with differents eviction policies. It's a mature library a with good support. There is a memcached api that wraps EhCache, specially developed for GAE support.

Regards,
  Jonathan.

Comment: Hi Jonathon. Thanks for your reply. I have looked into EhCache but I couldn't earlier, and still can't find a memcached api wrapper. Would you supply a link to it for me please?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It's not an memcache api wrapper, it's a way to use memcacheg from ehcache to combine the two cache solutions.
http://ehcache.org/documentation/googleappengine.html